# What does 判断裁量 mean here?

Tags: word-choice, words, anime

I have another sentence I'm grappling with *[see footnote for context]:

> キラかどうかの判断{はんだん}裁量{さいりょう}にはなりえない

I'm pretty sure from my dictionaries that 判断 means "judgement" but cannot figure out what makes sense for 裁量. All I can find is "admeassure[ment]", "discretion" or "judgement" again, which would be weird, because the compound would mean "judgement judgement". None of these options seem to make sense, so some interpretation help would be appreciated.

I understand the rest of the grammar. Whatever this word compound is "cannot become", which in English would mean "cannot be [in the future]". Thus it's crucial to understand this compound.

The translation reads "I won't be able to use this to figure out whether or not he's Kira." so the translators seemed to have just ignored one or both words from the compound.

Note on context:

> The speaker is a detective who is playing tennis with
>   a suspect in the "Kira" case in order to try to figure him out. Kira
>   is a notorious serial killer.

Dictionaries:

> http://jisho.org/ [wwwdjic];
>    http://ejje.weblio.jp/

Comment: 「判断[材料]{ざいりょう}」の間違いだと思います・・

Comment: "Judgement materials / ingredients"?

Comment: 画像: https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5Pb4.png ALC: [判断材料](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E5%88%A4%E6%96%AD%E6%9D%90%E6%96%99)

Comment: そうですね、"material for judgment", つまり "basis for a decision" "sufficient data on which to base a decision"  みたいな。。

Comment: @naruto わ、すげーｗ　そんな画像どうやって見つけてくるの～

Comment: @Naruto　どこに漫画を日本語でオンラインで読めますか。とこからこの画像ですか。見つかったことがないですから...

Comment: @Chocolate おなじこと書きました、笑

Comment: Sorry my japanese is bad haha. Thank you guys for all the help since I joined! You've been answering most of my questions! :)

Comment: That was captured from my Kindle library :)

Comment: ah too bad. Thanks for the help nonetheless :)

Comment: I see that this has been put on hold. It has been resolved and there's no point of editing it. However I am wary to delete it because I don't want to get banned from asking questions. Can someone advise?

Comment: @DelectableTea Don't worry too much.. You won't get banned just because your question was put on hold, so I think you could just leave this as it is...

Comment: @DelectableTea You can leave the question as it is. It's closed because there are no meaningful answers other than identifying the typo. There is no such thing as a ban for having a question closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that this is a mistake and should read, 「判断 **材料{ざいりょう}**」.

It would be easy to mistype 材料{ざいりょう} as 裁量{さいりょう}.

Comment: Oh, I just noticed chocolate's comment. So, I agree then.